# applying the same solver for complex matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let assume an equation A x = b, where A is a real n x n matrix, b is a real valued vector of length n and x is the solution vector of this  linear system.

We can find the solution of x by finding the inverse of A.

```
B= inv(A)
```

And therefore

```
x =A^{-1}b. 

x= B*b
```

Can I apply the same solver if A and b are complex?

EDIT: I'm looking for  explanation why it should work. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try it? Simple enough....

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation to learn about [solving linear systems](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html) with Matlab.

Comment: I mean after doing that operation, if i want to verify the result that it is correct, how to do that?

Comment: @SabbirHasan If you were to try it, choose a matrix `C` and a vector `z`, then compute `x = Cz`.  Now solve for `z`.  You know what it is because you chose it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.  Better in `Matlab` would be `x = A\b`.  That will usually get the answer faster and more accurately.

Comment: thanks for your answer. could you please write the reasoning that why  it should work for complex matrix too?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that question.  It's pretty much the definition of inverse.  It could be in some case (as with real matrices) that there is no inverse, but if there's an inverse it's defined to have the property that you're describing. @SabbirHasan The question really should be the other way around if at all - Why would it NOT work for complex matrices.

Answer (score 0):

In short yes, it works for any matrices irrespective of the field. (Well, at least real or complex field works.)

I think your question is whether B exists or not. It does as long as the determinant of B is non-zero. Vice versa.